# Identifying objects generated through framework and not built through raw HTML

Tags: selenium-webdriver, sproutcore, browser-automation

I have a scenario where i am unable to identify some of my objects on page. They don't have a unique identifier (like name, class, id). Our Dev team uses a JS framework which generates models, views, controllers etc and assigns id's dynamically. Also there are many children views which get dynamically generated with dynamic id's.

So i cannot use id's as it changes. I don't want to use xpath as it is not the industry standard. I tried css-selector but it gives me a long path not sure if that's a right way.

I wanted to know from all of you, is it a right practice to add extra attributes to an object in the development code for testing purpose ? Or is there any better way of handling these scenarios?

Comment: What does "xpath ... is not the industry standard" mean? See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/

Comment: @Siking: Sorry, my english is bad. I was trying to say that application i am using is brittle and keep changing. So i was told that identifying using location is not suggestible for these kinds of applications.

Comment: You were told wrong. Using the correct XPath is often the most stable option you can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're actually using SproutCore, you can easily add a `classNames` ([doc link](http://docs.sproutcore.com/#doc=SC.View&method=classNames&src=false)) or `layerId` ([doc link](http://docs.sproutcore.com/#doc=SC.View&method=layerId&src=false)) property to any view to make the CSS selectors shorter.

For instance:

```
MyApp.MainListView = SC.ListView.extend({
  layerId: 'my_special_view',
  classNames: 'my-special-class',

  content: ["Hi", "Foo", "Bar"],

  exampleView: SC.ListItemView.extend({
    classNames: 'my-special-list-class'
  })
})
```

**Note:** You will want to only use the `layerId` property if you're positive that there will only be 1 instance of the view on the screen, otherwise, the `classNames` property is the better way to go.

I would recommend adding some class names that are not testing specific, but that allow you to use shorter CSS selectors.

Comment: Again if you're using SproutCore, here's a very handy Chrome plugin which in the console gives you the currently-selected element's view with `$0v` – https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sproutcore-debug/kdjpmpfkllnnjndcfoefebpajggihpni

Comment: Also, if this isn't quite getting at your need, some sample HTML and/or sample SC code would help us get closer.

Comment: @Dave: Do we have something like that for firefox?

Comment: Afraid only Chrome at the moment. It should be easy to port over, but nobody's done so.